# How can I get my collections (and data in general) from cloud.mongodb.com?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

This is exactly my code. I've purposely let the Main method, so that you can see the whole thing.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv:://MyDatabaseUser:MyDatabaseUserPassword@cluster0.re2kq.mongodb.net/LiviuTestDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

            var database = client.GetDatabase("LiviuTestDb");
            var myCollections = database.ListCollections();
        }
```

I am getting a ConnectionTimeOutException. The credentials are correct - the user has read write to any database.

This is how my (only) cluster looks like (as simplistic as possible):

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you drop the db name from the connection string?

`var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://MyDatabaseUser:MyDatabaseUserPassword@cluster0.re2kq.mongodb.net");`

Comment: Same thing. Btw, it is mongodb+srv, not mongodb in connection string, I've just corrected the question.

Comment: ```var collections = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@my-cluster.pctjl.azure.mongodb.net").GetDatabase("Accounts").ListCollections().ToList();``` This works for me, if I do set an incorrect password I get a timeout so check your creds again - you may need to encode your password if you have special characters. [If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /, or the percent sign % character, use percent encoding.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've even deleted my cluster and created a new one slecting azure - hoping that it will be like yours. I created another user will all permissions ... it just does not want.